# Splunk - Adjusting source file timestamp

Tags: timestamp, splunk, adjustment

**Given**:

- I have two log files (file_1, file_2)
- Each from a different server (server_1, server_2).
- The servers are not property synchronized via ntpd.
  (Example: server_1 is 13 seconds ahead of server_2.)
- I do not have the ability to adjust or correct the server times.
- I am the Splunk user, not the Splunk administrator.

**Problem**: After ingesting each of the log files, the events are off by 13 seconds (obviously).

**Question**: Can I adjust the _time for all events in source=file_2 by 13 seconds so the events line up correctly in search results, graphs, etc.?

*(Note: this is a simple break down of the more complex problem.  I have thousands of logs from hundreds of servers.  I cannot simply re-run/create these logs.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do set the Splunk timestamp to whatever you want simply be overwriting the _time field for those events:

```
<any base search> source=file_2  | eval _time=_time+13
```

We can use an eval if statement to view all events and update the time only for file_2

```
<any base search> | eval _time=if(source=="file_2", _time+13, _time)
```